# Using python but cannot run after adding lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new in python and I want do something simple, but it is not working.

How can I, for example, in a while loop do something in multiple lines?

```
i=0
while i < 2:
    print i
    i += 1
```

This is not working! When I put enter after `print i` it executed my code, and returns some errors

I'm using Python 2.7.

[image]

Comment: What error does it return? Without that error we can't tell you what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't indent `print i`.

```
while i < 2:
print i
...
```

won't work.

```
while i < 2:
    print i
    ...
```

will. In many languages whitespace (including indentation) doesn't matter - you can have whatever spaces/tabs/newlines you want without it affecting how the code is interpreted. This is not the case with Python though - indentation matters. As Gary Walker mentioned in his answer, you can also have a problem when you mix tabs and spaces - it can't just look like the indentation is the same, you need to have the same number of spaces/tabs each time.

Comment: thnx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using python 2.7 idle

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> i=0
>>> while i < 2:
    print i
    i +=1


0
1
>>>
```

If you are getting something else, you likely have a problem where you are mixing tabs and spaces or suchlike. You code looks fine as is (assuming you wanted 0 and 1 as outputs)

Comment: I see you already have the answer re: indentation.